# Index defragmentation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

Hi any body help to tell me how to create a Procedure to defrag index on a daily basis in MS SQL Server 2000.

Appreciate your answers

Joseph

Answer (score 2):

One of the simplest ways:

```
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'DBCC DBREINDEX (''?'', '''', 90) '
```

There are several other alternatives where folk has out together some intelligent code, but I've not used them

- [Ola Hallengren](http://ola.hallengren.com/) (SQL 2005+ only?)
- [SQL fool](http://sqlfool.com/2009/03/automated-index-defrag-script/)